# How to configure Share Point 2010 on windows 7 with windows authentication

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have already install `sql server 2008 r2` which is login by using windows authentication.

And then after install Sharepoint2010 foundation on my Windows7 Ultimate OS.

Now Next step is SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. Click on next button i reach to **Connect to server farm** where is select Create new server farm and click to Next.

[image]

Then It Popup with below screen,
[image]

I have problem here is that it require Database access account with UserName and Password and UserName in form `DOMAIN\User` , but i dont have User Name with domain,then i create login user for sql server and it have name like SharePointUser with Password. There is no domain name.

I tried to enter user Name like `Aamir-PC\SharePointUser`, but gives error like User Name is invalid. The Account must have valid domain account. Even i tried username like `SharePointUser` but same error again.

I also tried to with create login account for windows with Name `SharePointUser` and given password same as sql user, but no success.

I search a lot but i did not find any solution for above problem.

Comment: after lots of try and error i did not find any solution of my problem. so finally  setup VMware environment

Answer (score 0):

Use `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` to create the Config DB. It accepts local account. After that you can re-run the Configuration Wizard and connect to an existing farm.

Comment: I tried this command in Power shell provide DatabaseName etc, it require passphrase, but i dont know passphrase.

Comment: You need to define NEW passphrase when creating new configuration database. Just come up with some password, and make a note of that, you will need it later if adding servers to the farm.

Comment: Trying to reset passphrase using http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/12/change-your-passphrase-using-powershell/

Comment: But getting error that,SP-PassPhrase : Cannot access local farm,verify the local farm is properly configured etc, In my DB i saw there is "SharePoint_AdminContent_9965f66c-3fbb-46b3-bc0c-833295a1623e" DB is there, but can not understand that why it is not configure